# Deriving Expression For QAOA Optimal Trial State Parameters

Tags: qiskit, mathematics, qaoa

I am going through the QAOA section in the [Qiskit Textbook - QAOA](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/qaoa.html#5.2-Optimal-trial-state-parameters) and am stuck in one of the steps. In section 5.2, the method for getting the Optimal Trial State Parameters are discussed. I do not follow how does Eq 2 follow from Eq 1.
[image: QAOA Doubt]
I have done some digging and have read other useful posts like [Quantum Approximate Optimization Algorithm explained](https://www.mustythoughts.com/quantum-approximate-optimization-algorithm-explained) and [How to do the direct evaluation by hand in QAOA algorithm](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13056/how-to-do-the-direct-evaluation-by-hand-in-qaoa-algorithm), and they have helped understand the problem better; but I am still unable to derive Equation 2 from 1. Any help or guidance would be appreciated. I am trying to find the optimal parameters of beta and gamma for different kind of graphs.